# Javascript input values disappear on button click

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to simulate data-entry for a form in vanilla Javascript. I cannot manipulate the HTML.

My code works fine until the final save button is clicked and then the filled-in inputs are cleared. How can I fill in the inputs and make sure that the data does not get cleared when I click on the final Save button?

HTML:

```
<input placeholder="What is the title" maxlength="50" type="text" data-vv-name="title" aria-label="form__text" class="form__text p--4" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">

<textarea placeholder="Describe it! (required)" maxlength="500" data-vv-name="description" aria-label="form__text" class="form__text listing-editor__description__input p--3" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" style="height: 135px;"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('.p--4')[0]) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.p--4')[0].value = "Wuthering Heights by Emily Brontë";
    document.querySelector('.p--4').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {
        'bubbles': true
    }));
}
if (document.querySelectorAll('.p--3')[0]) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.p--3')[0].value = "Wuthering Heights is a novel by Emily Brontë published in 1847 under her pseudonym Ellis Bell. Brontë's only finished novel, it was written between October 1845 and June 1846. Wuthering Heights and Anne Brontë's Agnes Grey were accepted by publisher Thomas Newby before the success of their sister Charlotte's novel Jane Eyre. After Emily's death, Charlotte edited the manuscript of Wuthering Heights and arranged for the edited version to be published as a posthumous second edition in 1850.";
    document.querySelector('.p--3').dispatchEvent(new Event('change', {
        'bubbles': true
    }));
}
```

Comment: Could it be because of the page refreshing?
can you try event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code example appears incomplete, but I assume those elements are inside a `form` element, and the button is a `button` element with `type="submit"`, and the button is inside the form.

If you want to prevent the submit button from posting the form, then you'll need to prevent the default behavior:

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Do stuff here...');
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```